# C# KeyEvent doesn't log the enter/return key

Tags: c#, events, keyboard-events, keyevent

I've been making this login form in C# and I wanted to 'submit' all the data as soon as the user either clicks on submit or presses the enter/return key.

I've been testing a bit with KeyEvents but nothing so far worked.

```
void tbPassword_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
}
```

The above code was to test if the event even worked in the first place.
It works perfectly, when I press 'd' it shows me 'd' when I press '8' it shows me '8' but pressing enter doesn't do anything.

So I though this was because enter isn't really bound to a character but it did show backspace, it worked just fine so it got me confused about why it didn't register my enter key.

So the question is:
**How do I log the enter/return key? and why doesn't it log the key press right right now like it should?**

note: I've put the event in a textbox

```
tbPassword.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(tbPassword_KeyPress);
```

So it fires when the enter button is pressed WHILE the textbox is selected (which is was the whole time of course) maybe that has something to do with the execution of the code.

Comment: I tested this on my computer, it worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have a button defined as the default action?

If so then that control will gobble up the Enter key.

And maybe that is your answer. You need to set the DefaultAction property to true on your submit button.

Comment: Sounds just like what I need. But how do I assign the DefaultAction to the button?

Comment: Thank you, I've figured it out now.
I made the button my default action but it didn't work.
But then I figured out it will trigger the button's "Click" event and I was working with the "MouseClick" event.
I guess that's the only difference between Click and MouseClick...

Answer (score 0):

Try the KeyDown event instead.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you subscribe to the event?
textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyDown);

Comment: Yes, I did do that, once again it works on all keys but the enter button.
Could this be a mistake of my pc instead of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use the "AcceptButton" of the form to set it to the submit button. Think that is what you what really...

Answer (score 0):

You have left out a vital bit, you must set the `Handled` property to true or false depending on the condition...

```
void tbPassword_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter){
      // This is handled and will be removed from Windows message pump
      e.Handled = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed I tend to forget adding that to my event handlers from time to time, thanks but it doesn't solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
textBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox1_KeyPress);

void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Key Pressed", "Enter Key Pressed", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you can add
     submitButton.PerformClick();
If you wish to trigger a button click event on your submitButton

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work...
Is there a way to check if the enter key is being somehow 'blocked' or interrupted somehow?

Answer (score 0):

go to your forms...

in the basic form change this

FormName.AcceptButton = buttonName;

this would read the key log file of enter... automatically..

you can do this if you dont want users to see accept button

buttonName.Visible = false;
FormName.AcceptButton = buttonName;

AcceptButton automatically reads the enter key from the keyboard